# Identifying dates in strings using NLTK

Tags: python, nltk

I'm trying to identify whether a date occurs in an arbitrary string. Here's my code:

```
import nltk

txts = ['Submitted on 1st January',
'Today is 1/3/15']

def chunk(t):
    w_tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(t)
    pt = nltk.pos_tag(w_tokens)
    ne = nltk.ne_chunk(pt)
    print ne

for t in txts:
    print t
    chunk(t)
```

The output I'm getting is

```
Submitted on 1st January
(S (GPE Submitted/NNP) on/IN 1st/CD January/NNP)
Today is 1/3/15
(S Today/NN is/VBZ 1/3/15/CD)
```

Clearly the dates are not being tagged. Does anyone know how to have dates tagged?

Thanks

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: @Leb I was hoping to have the dates extracted. .ne_chunk() is supposed to extract entities like dates, right? I'm not sure if I'm doing it right by calling `pos_tag` first.

Comment: You have a string and you are trying to find out if a certain date is somewhere in this string? Or you want to find and extract all the dates from the string?

Comment: @Joe I'm trying to find out if a date exists in the input string, without needing to find those dates.

Comment: What is the exact date you are trying to find?

Comment: I mean if you just need to know if a certain date is in a string, you don't need `nltk` it's easy to do it without it.

Comment: No specific date but any date in an arbitrary string.

Comment: can you show me the exact format of the date you are looking for? Like this: June 27, 2015 or other format?

Comment: I'm hoping for as many reasonable formats as possible - from 1/1/70 to 3rd Jan. Because of this, I haven't got an exhaustive list.

Comment: I just edited my answer check if this works for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I took the date example from your comment **1/1/70** but this regex code will also find them if they are formatted differently like 1970/01/20 or 2-21-79

```
import re
x = 'asdfasdf sdf5sdf asd78fsadf 1/1/70 dfsdg fghdfgh 1970/01/20 gfh5fghh sdfgsdg 2-21-79 sdfgsdgf'
print re.findall(r'\d+\S\d+\S\d+', x)
```

Output:

```
['1/1/70', '1970/01/20', '2-21-79']
```

OR,

```
y = 'Asdfasdf Ddf5sdf asd78fsadf Jan 3 dfsdg fghdfgh February 10 sdfgsdgf'
print re.findall(r'[A-Z]\w+\s\d+', y)
```

Output:

```
['Jan 3', 'February 10']
```

Comment: Well, I'm hoping to extract dates of other patterns, e.g., Jan 3, 3rd Jan, January 3, etc.

Comment: @Kar you know it's very difficult to find anything like this, if you knew the format of just one date, we can easily fond them all. In any case, I updated my answer for Jan 3

Comment: @Kar timex.py has all those formats included in it. If you use `findall` you'll need to create a whole list that already exists. No need to reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 3):

NLTK will not by itself detect Dates, but combine it with [Stanford's Named Entity Tagger](http://nlp.stanford.edu:8080/ner/process), and it will. It can be difficult finding the right set of instructions that work effectively so here are a couple links:

```
Stanford tagger site - look for downloads: https://nlp.stanford.edu/software/CRF-NER.shtml
Stanford tagger API - http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.tag.html#nltk.tag.stanford.StanfordTagger
```

Sorry, the linking wouldn't work for these last two.

Here is the code I used:

```
from nltk.tag import StanfordNERTagger
stanfordClassifier = '/path/to/classifier/classifiers/english.muc.7class.distsim.crf.ser.gz'
stanfordNerPath = '/path/to/jar/stanford-ner-2017-06-09/stanford-ner.jar'
st = StanfordNERTagger(stanfordClassifier, stanfordNerPath, encoding='utf8')
result = st.tag(word_tokenize("The date is October 13, 2017"))
print (result)
```

Answer (score 2):

NLTK `ne_chunk()` does not recognize dates by default. You'll need to use `timex.py` by first obtaining it from [nltk_contrib](https://github.com/nltk/nltk_contrib/blob/master/nltk_contrib/timex.py).

Comment: I've just tried `timex.py` but it seems to use only a handful of regex patterns. For instance, it can't identify any date in `'Submitted on 1st January'` and only picks out `Today` when given `'Today is 1/3/15'`.

Comment: i couldnt find it usefull , as it was able to detect  "2014-2018"  , It main limitation RE. Should have used Nltk instead .