# Named Entity Recognition in NLP using Python

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp

I have lots of CVs text documents. In that, there is different formats of dates are available e.g. *Birthdate* - 12-12-1995, *Experience-year* - 2000 PRESENT *or* 1995-2005 *or* 5 years of experience *or* 1995/2005, *Date-of-Joining* - 5th March, 2015 etc. From these data I want to extract only years of experience. **How can I do this in Python using NLP?** Please answer.

I have tried with following :

```
#This gives me all the dates from documents
import datefinder
data = open("/home/system/Desktop/samplecv/5c22fcad79fcc1.33753024.txt")
str1 = ''.join(str(e) for e in data)
matches = datefinder.find_dates(str1)
for match in matches:
    print(match)
```

Comment: I have got all the dates from different documents. But I want the dates of particular years of experience. @ Klaus D.

Comment: Sorry, but I did not ask what your problem was, I asked what you have tried to solve it. Here on SO it is expected that you try to solve the problem first and share your process with us.

Comment: I updated my post @Klaus D.

Answer (score 0):

If you already have extracted the dates then it seems like what you're missing is the "type of date" each is. If datefinder isn't able to keep track of the positional structure of the dates within the corpus then date extraction using it won't be too useful.

However, this isn't just a entity recognition problem. You'll have to pair a NER with a POS tagger (and maybe even a Syntatic Dependency Parser) [Spacy](https://spacy.io/usage/spacy-101) is a good one.

You should first run a POS tagger on your corpus and see whether it picks up phrases like "Experience" or "Work History". If not, you should add your own labels to it so that it will specifically tag those words as you desire.

Then you can run a NER to pick up Dates. Keep in mind that the NER at best will tag all your dates as DATE entities and will not be able to find the distinction between what type of dates these are.

You'll have to link the respective date to a preceding or following Part of Speech using some language grammar or a regular expression.

For instance you can associate all Dates that follow the word Experience to the Experience POS Tag.

Alternatively you can try NLTK (which is an alternative to Spacy but you'll need to run the same pipeline with it too). Read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31088509/identifying-dates-in-strings-using-nltk) for more.

Comment: How to match date before or after 'experience' keyword? @HakunaMaData

Comment: If datefinder is simply extracting the dates from the corpus then it isn't going to be terribly useful. What you need is a combination of POS Tagging, Dependency Parsing as well as NER. I have edited my answer appropriately.

Comment: I'm very newbie to a Python. Can you please tell me how to make a combination of POS Tagging? And Dependency Parsing with NER? @HakunaMaData

Comment: @Heena you can start off with Regex as HakunaMaData said, your question is a little too broad to be answered here.